# nodemon + express, listen port =?

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I create a simple node project using express:

```
npm install -g express-generator
express test
cd test/ && npm install
PORT=3000 npm start
```

So this gets the test app up and running on port 3000. Great. Now I'd like to use `nodemon` to run this project. I've installed it:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

In the gihub README it is run the same way as node. This is a bit confusing, because the new way of starting node is `npm start` not `node`. So I tried:

```
$ PORT=3000 nodemon ./app.js 
13 May 23:41:16 - [nodemon] v1.0.18
13 May 23:41:16 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
13 May 23:41:16 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
13 May 23:41:16 - [nodemon] starting `node ./app.js`
13 May 23:41:16 - [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

But when I try to connect, there's nothing there. I confirmed that with:

```
lsof -i TCP:3000
```

Which returned nothing. Normally (with `npm start`) it returns:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    18746 user   10u  IPv4 433546      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

Can anyone tell whats wrong here? 
How is it possible to get the app to listen on the specified port with `nodemon`?

my setup:

```
npm -v
1.3.21
node -v
v0.10.24
nodemon -v
v1.0.18
express -V
4.2.0
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

in **package.json**

```
  "scripts":{
    // "start": "node ./bin/www"
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
   }
```

the following would now be equivalent:

```
$ npm start
$ nodemon ./bin/www
```

Comment: Excellent. This answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I did not understand, how does this specify port for nodemon? I tried following this but I still face the same problem - nothing listening on port 3000

Comment: This one does not change the listening port, it only uses nodemon to start the project than pure nodejs

Answer (score 13):

This also works: Include this in your app.js (it does the same thing as the neolivz4ever said)

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

you too use define your for nodemon:

`$ nodemon --inspect ./bin/www 3000`

Comment: 'node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are now deprecated. Use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the way to specify the port number with nodemon + express-generator, go to bin/www and change the line

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
```

to specific number. For example,

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '1234');
```

Answer (score -1):

Additionally, some times, the port are just in use. If the other solutions not work for you, try change the port. It may be in use for some other node instance.